# Powershell function executing a stored procedure returns a -1 and does not load data in table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

Below is the function in PowerShell script to execute a stored procedure which populates a table in the database. When executed, the output shows -1. And the table does not have any data loaded. Is there any other debug statements that I can add to figure out why the stored procedure seems to not execute?
When executing the stored procedure in SSMS, it loads the data into the table as expected but when executing it using the script below, it doesn't load anything in the table.

```
function ExecuteStoredProcedure(
        [string] $storedProcedureName,
        [string] $connectionString
)
{ 
    try
    {
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $conn.ConnectionString = $connectionString
        $close=($conn.State -eq [System.Data.ConnectionState]'Closed')

        if ($close) {
            $conn.Open()
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName)($($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)): $($_.InvocationInfo.Line) Exception: $($_.Exception)"
    }

    try
    {
        $cmd = new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
        $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
        $cmd.CommandText = $storedProcedureName
        $cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Write-Output $cmd

        if ($close) {
            $conn.Close()
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName)($($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)): $($_.InvocationInfo.Line) Exception: $($_.Exception)"
    }
}

$storedProcedureName = "[dbo].[spPopulateTable]"
#Usage
ExecuteStoredProcedure -connectionString $connectionString -storedProcedureName $storedProcedureName
```

Here is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\cenko> function ExecuteStoredProcedure(
        [string] $storedProcedureName,
        [string] $connectionString
)
{ 
    try
    {
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $conn.ConnectionString = $connectionString
        $close=($conn.State -eq [System.Data.ConnectionState]'Closed')

        if ($close) {
            $conn.Open()
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName)($($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)): $($_.InvocationInfo.Line) Exception: $($_.Exception)"
    }

    try
    {
        $cmd = new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
        $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
        $cmd.CommandText = $storedProcedureName
        $cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Write-Output $cmd

        if ($close) {
            $conn.Close()
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName)($($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)): $($_.InvocationInfo.Line) Exception: $($_.Exception)"
    }
}

$storedProcedureName = "[dbo].[spPopulateTable]"
#Usage
ExecuteStoredProcedure -connectionString $connectionString -storedProcedureName $storedProcedureName
-1


Connection              : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
NotificationAutoEnlist  : True
Notification            : 
Transaction             : 
CommandText             : [dbo].[spPopulateTable]
ColumnEncryptionSetting : UseConnectionSetting
CommandTimeout          : 0
CommandType             : StoredProcedure
DesignTimeVisible       : True
Parameters              : {}
UpdatedRowSource        : Both
Site                    : 
Container               :
```

Comment: The `-1` is the output from the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` call, which is _implicitly_ output by the function; to suppress this output, use `$null = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mklement0. But are there any other debug statements that can help me troubleshoot why the stored procedure is not working? When I execute it in SSMS, it works fine and loads data as expected but when it is executed from the above script, it doesn't load any data in the table.

Comment: Personally, i know little about these types, unfortunately; the only other thing I noticed is that you're passing `$sql` to the  `system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` constructor, whose value isn't defined in the function; then again, you're seemingly overwriting later by assigning to `.CommandText` anyway. Final thoughts: Is the name format `'[dbo].[spPopulateTable]'` - with the `[` and `]` characters - really supported in the `.CommandText` argument?

Comment: @mklemet0 the brackets ([ ]) was not an issue with the .CommandText argument. I found out that it was an insert permission on the table was not granted to the service account  which prevented it from loading the data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It was an insert permission issue on the table that prevented it from loading the data. Once the service account was given the write access, the stored procedure loaded the data as expected.